# Python twisted http resource getChild with more than 2 layers

Tags: python, http, web, twisted

When generating dynamic resource using python twisted.web, how to pass down getChild for more than 2 layers ?

A concrete example from following page http://jcalderone.livejournal.com/48953.html
This example can generate dynamic page for request of form "/" or "/year". 
I want to extend the example so that it can also support GET request of form "/year/month", what code change is needed?